# c# - envio de arquivo no ftp funciona apenas na primeira vez

Tags: c#, ftp, webrequest

Tenho uma função que faz o envio de arquivos para um ftp, na primeira vez que uso ela funciona perfeitamente, porém quando vou usar pela segunda vez ele fica travado na linha: using (Stream writer = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())

Segue o código completo da função:

```
private void EnviarFTP(string CaminhoArquivoLocal, string CaminhoFTP, string NomeArquivoFTP)
{
    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse;
    string sURI = "ftp://" + txtFTPServer.Text + "/" + CaminhoFTP;
    try
    {
        if (!CheckFileExistsFtp(sURI))
        {
            ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(sURI));
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFTPUser.Text, ftpPass);
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            ftpStream.Close();
            response.Close();
        }

        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(sURI + NomeArquivoFTP));
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpRequest.Proxy = null;
        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(txtFTPUser.Text, ftpPass);
        ftpRequest.Timeout = 10000000;
        ftpRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000000;

        //Seleção do arquivo a ser enviado
        FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo(CaminhoArquivoLocal);
        byte[] fileContents = new byte[arquivo.Length];

        using (FileStream fr = arquivo.OpenRead())
        {
            fr.Read(fileContents, 0, Convert.ToInt32(arquivo.Length));
        }

        using (Stream writer = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writer.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }

        //obtem o FtpWebResponse da operação de upload
        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        txtMsg.Text += Environment.NewLine + "ERRO=> " + webex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não, ele simplesmente fica travado, me parece que algum dado armazenado da primeira vez faz com que trava na segunda, mas eu to fechando as conexões, nao entendo porque.

Comment: Quando o upload já foi concluído? quais são os tamanhos dos arquivos?

Comment: no momento em que esta enviando o arquivo using (Stream writer = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()). sao arquivos pequenos, 13 kb

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer usando essa dll (FTP.ddl) :

https://www.limilabs.com/ftp/download
**(Ftp.dll zip archive)**

aqui tem os exemplos que precisar :

https://www.limilabs.com/ftp/samples